# Passing Variables Between Two Classes

Tags: php, oop

I have two classes that implement the same interface.

In class one I have an array variable called author. Typically to pass variables between two different functions in the same class I use `$this->author;` once it's been set.

This doesn't seem to work between two classes. Can someone please clarify how I would call a variable from class one in class two?

Thanks!

Comment: In OOP, You can not use same variable in same class, You should have base class, Both class will extends to base class and take value

Comment: Have you implied the case of modification of the same variable between classes?

Comment: What's the goal are you trying to achieve by passing variables between two classes that implement the same interface?

Comment: you have to make one class as parent and second class as child. then you can do this

Comment: Hi are either of the provided answers any good? You've written nothing in response to either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php for nomanclature of object-oriented design concepts.

When you use `$this->author` you are not passing variables between functions. The two functions are referencing the same variable of the object that both the functions belong to.

`author` is a property of the class.

There is no place that you could put a variable and have it referenced by two different classes. However, you could use a `public` property on one class and reference that from any other class.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php for public properties.

But that technique doesn't capture the scheme you have with two functions referencing a common property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Traits (horizontal inheritance) http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.traits.php

Although it will only help you if your variable will only be consulted and not to be modified. Thats because, traits allow you to specify static properties, but each class using that trait has independent instances of those properties.

http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.traits.php#107965

This is an example:

```
trait myTrait {
  public $sameVariable = 'shared';

    public function getMessage() { 
        echo $this->sameVariable;
    }
}

class A {
    use myTrait;
    public function getMessageA() { 
        echo $this->sameVariable;           //Prints shared
        $this->sameVariable = 'changed';
        echo $this->sameVariable;           //prints changed
    }
}


class B {
    use myTrait;
    public function getMessageB() { 
        echo $this->sameVariable;           //Prints shared
    }
}

$a = new A();
$b = new B();

$a->getMessageA();
$b->getMessageB();
```

This permits you reuse the variable having it in a Trait instead of duplicate your code, but i don't understand your case so well. So that maybe this is not what you want =/